# Get Javascript code as string from url with Python

Tags: javascript, python, string, url

I am trying to get a script written in Javascript from a URL with Python 2.7. I have tried using urllib, urllib2, and requests. They all return an empty string. The url contains no HTML elements it is just the javascript code.

Here's the link: http://go.pub2srv.com/apu.php?zoneid=676495

And what I have tried:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://go.pub2srv.com/apu.php?zoneid=676495')
print r.text
```

returns `u' '`, same with urllib and urllib2.
Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** OK I got it to work. Looks like the website was filtering user agents. 
This thread helped me out. [Python request.get(url) returns empty content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491872/python-request-geturl-returns-empty-content)

`import requests
url = 'http://go.pub2srv.com/apu.php?zoneid=676495'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`

Thanks everyone.

Comment: when I ran your code I didnt get an empty string I got something like this `(function(options, lary) {....`

Comment: This is what it should be yet I still get the empty string. Response is 200 OK. Are you on python 3 by any chance?

Comment: I also get nothing when using urllib2, or requests in Python 2.6 and Python 3.6. But I _can_ get the JavaScript using wget. I _guess_ it might be a cookie issue (the header sets 3 cookies), but requests normally handles cookies ok.

Comment: @aleksiy123 This seems to be interesting and a bit weird too even i am using python2.7.6 on linux. I tried it through console by the way though it shouldnt matter

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import urllib2

data = urllib2.openurl("http://onclickads.net/apu.php?zoneid=676495")
js = ""
for lines in data.readlines():
   js = js +lines

print js
```

Comment: I still get the empty string. Response is 200 OK. Not sure what the problem is.