# lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

I am writing a Google Analytics scraper for research purposes. This is my first post, so sorry in advance if the format is wrong. It might be a noob question (and I have tried as suggested in #[25491872](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491872/python-request-geturl-returns-empty-content)), but here it comes anyways.

Python version: 2.7.6

Requests version: 2.2.1

etree.LXML_VERSION: (3, 3, 3, 0)

lxml is returning ParserError:

> `lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty`

The error part of the code looks like this:

```
user_agent={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/53.0.2785.143 Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}

for _ in range(row_count):  
    url="http://"+linecache.getline("sourcelist.csv", i).rstrip('\n') #the error only occurs on a specific webpage: http://www.mixednews.ru

    headers = {"User-Agent": , "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
    print url
    page=requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)

    print page.headers
    print repr(page)

    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        i =i+1
        fields=[url,["TimeOut"]]
        with open ("output.csv", "ab") as o:
            writer=csv.writer(o)
            writer.writerows([fields])
        print "timeout"
        continue

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: #HTTPSConnectionPool:
        i=i+1
        fields=[url, "URL not valid"]
        with open ("output.csv", "ab") as o:
            writer=csv.writer(o)
            writer.writerows([fields])
        print "URL not valid"
        continue

    except requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError:
        i=i+1
        fields=[url, "Host server error"]
        with open ("output.csv", "ab") as o:
            writer=csv.writer(o)
            writer.writerows([fields])
        print "Host server error"
        continue        
    tree=html.fromstring(page.content) #error
```

page.headers and repr(page) returns content:

> CaseInsensitiveDict({'wp-super-cache': 'Served supercache file from PHP', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding,Cookie', 'server': 'nginx', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'cache-control': 'max-age=3, must-revalidate', 'date': 'Sun, 12 Mar 2017 13:36:05 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'})
>
> Response [200]

Any ideas to why this is happening, and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: What is `html` variable? Try using `lxml.html.parse`. Also print the `page.content` to be sure it is not empty.